# Find the solution for $|x|=\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

I checked this on a graphing calculator and noticed there are two solutions for this. How do I find them? Can they be found without the help of a calculator? They were some very arbitrary values, so this there some sort, patter (if that’s the right word to describe this), present in this?

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number and this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html

Comment: [A003957](http://oeis.org/A003957)

Comment: Both sides of your equation are even functions of $x$, so the solutions are negatives of each other. There is no closed formula for the solution, but you can approximate it as well as you wish using iterations or Newton-Rhapson (faster).

Comment: You can find a very good precision of the solution but not exactly the solution.

Comment: As I have found out, much to my dismay, I am treading on unfamiliar waters here. Honestly, this way beyond my current scope of studies, so I will pull back immediately. Thanks!